# Z and T score to probability in python3

Tags: python-3.x, probability

I'm developing a basic calculator that will take some data and return the Z and T scores. I need to check the values against the T and Z tables. However, the only idea I get, is to use 2D array, and recreate the same lists that any person would use to calculate them. But that would mean loading a big table into the memory. Is there any function I could use in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to convert the Z and T scores to p-values of the corresponding distributions, the z-distribution and the t-distribution. To do so you can use the following survival functions from the library 'scipy.stats':

1. For the Z score:

   ```
   # one-sided (multiply by 2 if two-sided)
   p_value = scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(Z))
   ```
2. For the T score:

   ```
   # one-sided (multiply by 2 if two-sided)
   p_value = scipy.stats.t.sf(abs(T))
   ```

Comment: Have a question, shouldnt i need to input the degrees of freedom?

Comment: No, these tests do not have degrees of freedom. As for the 'abs()' (the absolute value), I wrote a comment yesterday but I do not see it anymore. For simplicity, yes, keep the absolute value and avoid differentiating between positive and negative values. Such distributions are symmetric.